# Git Everything is-up-to-date (not)

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I've been looking everywhere but I can't push any files to my git repository. It stuck on the default quick guide (I think its the everything is up to date issue). Here's what I've done

[image]

also you will see http://52.76.185.100:3000 (http) there is no s because i didn't set it up. But every time i try to push files or anything the same output will result branch master.... everything up to date.

there is no typical writing objects or anything like that or counting objects message when i push

Comment: What's `52.76.185.100`? Is it not te same machine (or a machine mounting the same disk) as localhost? This looks like a situation where you have nothing to push because the commit is already there.

Comment: Private IPs
172.31.23.2 IPv4 Public IP
52.76.195.180? It's my elastic ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialized a Git repo...in a (bare) git repo year_1.git!
A bare repo should have any file beside Git internal files.

When you push, you are actually pushing the parent Git repo, which has not changed. Hence the everything up to date.

You should instead clone that `http://52.76.185.100:3000/ubuntu/year_1.git` repo elsewhere, and add files there, instead of working in the bare repo lfolder itself.

```
 cd /a/apth
 git clone http://52.76.185.100:3000/ubuntu/year_1.git
 cd year_1
 # add files
 # git add; git commit; git push
```